# RoR - Private Messages Reply Algorithm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

I've got the following private message model

```
belongs_to :from_user, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :to_user, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :thread, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: 'parent_message_id'
has_many :replies, class_name: 'Message'
attr_accessible :subject, :body
scope :original_message, where("parent_message_id IS NULL")
```

I've got the views all set up to display the messages as a thread, and I want to put a quick reply form at the bottom. I'm completely brain freezing on the best way to set to_user, since any given message in the thread may belong to the current user or the user on the other end. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are only two users in the thread then we can assume that either `from_user` or `to_user` is `current_user`, which means the one that isn't `current_user` is the other party. And so:

```
orig_msg = @thread.messages.original_message

if orig_msg.from_user == current_user
  other_user = orig_msg.to_user
else
  other_user = orig_msg.from_user
end
```

Or:

```
other_user = orig_msg.to_user
other_user = orig_msg.from_user unless orig_msg.from_user == current_user
```

Or:

```
other_user = orig_msg.from_user == current_user ?
               orig_msg.to_usr : orig_msg.from_user
```

Comment: Would this work in the model layer? `def other_user(user)
    from_user == user ? to_user : from_user
  end`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement and what I did was added javascript to move the reply textarea around based on where the 'Reply' button the thread was clicked.

On Reply, you set the variable to which post the current user is replying to and based on the owner of the post you can add the to_user

If its a flat conversation (like in a forum) or a threaded conversation like in [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/), this should work .